# Report generation in sonarqube 5.5

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube 5.5 for static code analysis.I am looking for solution to generate the analysis report automatically . Please let me know if anyone is having any solution for that.
I have used the webservices API to get the report, but its returning only first 100 issues.

Comment: what do you call the analysis report? do you want to launch an analysis regularly? which WS have you used? what are you trying to get?

Comment: Hi Teryk, I am looking for overall code analysis report after every running of the sonarqube code review. Everytime i am triggering the sonarqube analysys through Jenkins. Hence need some automatic report which can be sent through notification. I know the report extract WS has depreciated in 5.5 version, though i have used sonar-ws-client-4.3. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **sonar-ws-client-4.3** then you can increase page count using **IssueQuery** class.

```
        List<Issue> issuesList = new ArrayList<Issue>();
        IssueClient issueClient = client.issueClient();
        IssueQuery query = IssueQuery.create();
        Issues issues = null;

        query.severities("BLOCKER","CRITICAL", "MAJOR");
        query.urlParams().put("types", "VULNERABILITY");
        query.resolved(false);

        int issueCount = 0;
        int numberOfPages = 7; // Number of issue pages 

        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++) {

            query.pageIndex(i);
            query.pageSize(500);

            issues = issueClient.find(query);
            issuesList.addAll(issues.list());

            System.out.println("In progress ...");
        }
```